# Glitched display for certain resolutions after my laptop felt on the ground

Tags: laptop, display, resolution, colors

I once made my Lenovo Thinkpad X230 fall to the ground.

Since that day, the laptop display has glitches only for some resolutions.

The native resolution of my screen is 1366x768.

Resolutions below 1320x768 show no glitches despite the fact I can see that the colors changed a bit, for example blue tends to be yellowish and so do white parts on youtube videos for example.

All the resolutions above are completely glitched.

Please find below a youtube video I made to make it clearer (I hope) :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SybzIwJhO-I&feature=share&fbclid=IwAR3W4iMZQRUoNcFPq9MUMAAF13gaAb4KUNUgQ_hewmh3clJLyzNwVXCESv8

Any idea how to fix this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem.

I simply unplugged then plugged again my screen connector, it seems like the cable was improperly connected.

The connector I am talking about : https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-3NN5SfDCmPk/XFdgx2pNlkI/AAAAAAAAyrI/MCGOzM9XgdsCsYwOJqWuF6c-cRttNFUfwCLcBGAs/s640/DSCF8486.jpeg

It's located behind the LCD display, the process to access the lcd display is described here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXcs43vXOu0

Now it's back to normal, I can enjoy the native resolution.

Hopefully this post can help someone.